# ExSheets fancy headings breaks

Tags: latex3, exsheets, xcoffins

## Remarks

From the `exsheets` documentation I grabbed a piece of code to produce fancy headings for questions and solution, but it breaks. It is the `fancy` heading style on page 49 and 50 in the current CTAN [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exsheets/exsheets_en.pdf) (2013-12-07).

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

% From the documentation page 49 and 50
\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{fancy}{default}{
    toc-reversed  = true,
    indent-first  = true,
    vscale        = 2,
    pre-code      = \rule{\linewidth}{1pt},
    post-code     = \rule{\linewidth}{1pt},
    title-format  = \large\scshape\color{exsheetsred},
    number-format = \large\bfseries\color{exsheetsblue},
    points-format = \itshape,
    join          = { number[r,B] title[l,B] (.333em,0pt) },
    attach        = {
        main[hc,vc]number[hc,vc](0pt,0pt);
        main[l,vc]points[r,vc](-\marginparsep,0pt)
    }
}

\SetupExSheets{headings=fancy}
\begin{document}

\begin{question}
    What does the following code do?
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

## Output

It seems to break inside `title[l,B]` in the line `join = { number[r,B] title[l,B] (.333em,0pt) }`.

```
Runaway argument?
B] (.333em,0pt)\s_obj_end \__prg_break_point:Nn \seq_map_break: {\__seq_pop_ite
m_def: \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \__exsheets_join_coffin_sequence:w.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> sheet1.tex

?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is quite obvious once you know what it is. Suppose you define a macro

```
\def\foo[#1](#2){...}
```

and use it like

```
\foo[1] (2)
```

You get an error

```
Runaway argument?
1] (2) 
! Paragraph ended before \foo was complete.
```

because it keeps looking for `](` and never finds it. The same thing is happening here. The lines of the `join` and `attach` keys basically are delimited arguments to internal commands. Your error comes from the line

```
join          = { number[r,B] title[l,B] (.333em,0pt) },
```

which should read

```
join          = { number[r,B]title[l,B](.333em,0pt) },
```

that is without the spaces in between. Then your code gives

[image]

The documentation is wrong which is a copy&paste error of mine: `exsheets` is implemented with `expl3` where spaces are ignored. When I copied the original code to the documentation I forgot to remove the dangerous spaces...

BTW: the code in the documentation serves as examples for own heading instances. If you just want to use the `fancy' style the following would do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[load-headings]{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{headings=fancy}
\begin{document}

\begin{question}
    What does the following code do?
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This kind of problems could be avoided with `\def\foo[#1]#2(#3)...` then testing whether `#2` is blank.  Alternatively, I think that `xparse` ignores spaces when looking for optional arguments except the last.